# How to compress data to send it with email

Tags: ios4

I am working on an application that needs a compressed file to be sent allong with the email. I can send the email successfully but what I want is to attach a file in COMPRESSED format with my email.
....please any one help me!!!

thanx in advance......

Answer (score 0):

look for a zip library (available in c, c#, I don't know about iphone though.. but I bet there is something:

[google it:](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7615-simple-objective-c-class-zip-unzip-zip-format-files.html)